# When compiling my client it says org.apache.commons.lang3.time.StopWatch doesn't exist while it is in my project, how come?

Tags: java, apache-commons

When compiling my project I get an error on the `org.apache.commons.lang3.time.StopWatch`, it says it doesn't exist.

This is the compiler:

```
@echo off
Title Compiler
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javac.exe" *.java
pause
```

while the "commons-lang3-3.4.jar" is in my project and I imported the StopWatch class in my code.

Screenshots in 1 image -> 
[image: here]

Any ideas?

Comment: @Pepjin how did you add the jar file to your project? I can see that you have 2 java setups. can you remove one from the project build content view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not specifying a class path when compiling. When compiling using `javac`, you need to specify the class path if you want to use libraries (other than those included in Java).

For example:

```
javac -cp .;lib\commons-lang.jar *.java
```

Where `.` denotes the current folder, and `lib\commons-lang.jar` the path to commons-lang (location is probably different for you).

Alternatively you could set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.

Note that if you had compiled through your IDE, instead of doing it yourself with a makeshift batch-file, it would probably have worked just fine.

Comment: That solved it. changed the above and added the classpath like so.

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javac.exe" -cp .;commons-lang3-3.5.jar *.java

Answer (score -1):

clean-up the class path. There are 2 JREs in your class-path. That my cause some compilation-errors. Don't forget to recompile your project.
And BTW: The current version of common-lang is 3.5.

Comment: The problem is not with compiling through the IDE, so this is irrelevant; the OP is using a custom batch-file to compile and hasn't specified a classpath.

Comment: See the part immediately below _"this is the compiler"_

Comment: Just for completion: It can cause problems, if the compilation is triggered from outside the IDE, except it is supported by a plugin (like maven).

Comment: Maybe, but that is unrelated to the actual problem in the question. Your answer is more of a comment to this specific question.